# Spacemacs: Layout specific python processes?

Tags: spacemacs, python

In the same spirit that Org Mode allows us to have multiple python SRC BLOCKS with different sessions running independently, **is it possible to have multiple Python shells running in different Layouts with Spacemacs?**

(Or not necessarely with spacemacs)

I know it is possible to start multiple shells by renaming the * Python * buffer. What happens then is that code is always sent to the new shell, so the old one becomes sort of useless.

Answer (score 2):

I set this up for myself using two custom Spacemacs layers: [org-extras](https://github.com/brandonwillard/spacemacs-custom/tree/master/layers/org-extras) and [python-extras](https://github.com/brandonwillard/spacemacs-custom/tree/master/layers/python-extras).

The first step involves forcing org-babel to use `python-mode`'s shell process naming (see [here](https://github.com/brandonwillard/spacemacs-custom/blob/master/layers/org-extras/packages.el#L37)), then the Python shell naming is amended to include the project name (see [here](https://github.com/brandonwillard/spacemacs-custom/blob/master/layers/python-extras/packages.el#L74)).

If you'd like, I could submit a PR to add these as toggle-able features in the default Python and/or Org layers in Spacemacs.